# hypothesis test based on a log linear equation

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, econometrics, terminology

The question I have to answer is the following:

Check statistically at the 0.01 level of significance whether there is any evidence that bill expenditures are income inelastic.

I have a log linear equation :`LN(Bill)= -9.4 + 1.781 * LN(Income)`

Can anyone tell me how I can run this hypothesis test?

Comment: I am not allowed to put in the `self study` tag, but put in some others. Add the `self study` tag or this question will likely be closed, which is possibly a shame since I may have given you directions to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the instructions i'll try to comply(my mother language is Greek) .I m a new user.Just for the history .The answer in the above question was a simple one sided t test of the kind:
Ho=b1>1 inelastic H1=b1<1 elastic where you reject the null .I ll post the university's answer as soon as i take it in my hands .I got an 8,3 out of 10.(That hurt a bit since i put a lot of effort in the assignment)The professor didn't accept the approach you suggested.Anyway i'm in general pleased since we are talking about assignments that are far above my league .

Answer (score 1):

A [total revenue test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_revenue_test) allows for the determination of elasticity. If an increase in price causes an increase in total revenue, then demand can be said to be inelastic, since the increase in price does not have a large impact on quantity demanded. If an increase in price causes a decrease in total revenue, then demand can be said to be elastic, since the increase in price has a large impact on quantity demanded.

I assume that "Bill" means "unit price", $P$. Income means total revenue, $R$, and number sold is $Q$. Then $R=P Q$, and $Q=f(P)$, and $E_d = - \frac{dQ}{dP} \cdot \frac{P}{Q}=-f'(P) \cdot \frac{P}{Q}$, where $E_d>1$ is elastic.

You were given that $\ln P\approx a+b\ln R$, where $a,b$ are constants. Thus, $P\approx e^{a+b \ln R}=e^a R^b$, $PQ=R\approx e^{\frac{\ln (P) -a}{b}}=e^{-a/b}P^{1/b}\rightarrow Q\approx \frac{e^{-a/b}P^{1/b}}{e^a R^b}\approx \frac{e^{-a/b}P^{1/b}}{e^a (e^{-a/b}P^{1/b})^b}\approx e^{-a/b}P^{1/b-1}$.

Then from the text of the total revenue test $ f(P)=Q\approx  e^{-a/b}P^{1/b-1}\rightarrow f'(P)\approx (1/b-1)e^{-a/b}P^{1/b-2}\rightarrow E_d = -f'(P) \cdot \frac{P}{Q}\approx -(1/b-1)e^{-a/b}P^{1/b-2}\frac{P}{e^{-a/b}P^{1/b-1}}=1-\frac{1}{b}$

From this, it would seem that the elasticity is only a function of $b$.

Assuming you have the logarithms of the data, you just do [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) and find the 99% confidence intervals for $b$. That should then give you the range of $E_d =1-\frac{1}{b}$. Assuming a 99% CI of $b$ of 0.054226927 to 0.064183547, $E_b$ should range from -17.44102285 to -14.580316868, which is less than 1 thus inelastic.

Comment: yes but don't i need to make a hypothesis test ?my F stat is equal to 485,767 while the F critical value is 1,56529546970032E-69.what would be the null hypothesis that should be rejected ?my p value is too small (1,11158720934812E-44) less than 0,01.i was thinking of claiming that the relationship is elastic since my b1 coefficient(1,781) is larger than 1.what do you think about it?

Comment: Well, I had to look up what elastic means. Is this a homework problem from some eco or business course?

Comment: Well this is an exersice from an MBA programme by the Hellenic Open University(EAP).

Comment: OK, then you need to do two things. 1) You need to select the `self study` tag, and if you want you can read about why at http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info 2) Modify your question so that it does not ask us to complete a homework assignment per se. For example, you might ask "How do I test for elasticity?" That way, you get what you need, and we do not break the rules.

Comment: Υour conclusions seems to be right .The Ed=1-1/b gives me a result 0,4386 (b=1,718).my intervals with 99% confidence are Lower 99%:0,054226927 and Upper 99% :0,064183547.So the elsticity found isn't included in this interval so i have to reject the null hypothesis which still we haven't concluded how it's supposed to be referred.

Comment: What are the 99% confidence intervals for b, please?

Comment: the confidence intervals are upper 0,0642 and lower 0,0542

Comment: I am guessing that your primary language of mathematical instruction is continental European, e.g., French, Polish etc. When using this site, please be careful to write numbers exchanging the commas and periods, e.g., for one million use 1,000,000.00 and not 1.000.000,00 as even a polyglot (i.e., me) finds that ambiguous.